# Reputation graph rendering - selected date range shows clumps of bars

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

[image: Screenshot of graph showing clumping]

The platform is Windows 10 (virtual desktop via Citrix), Chrome Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (32-bit).  Two screens 1680x1050.

If I select a date range on the reputation graph on the user profile page, the graph shows clumps of bars that don't appear to align with the actual distribution of the rep. (see screenshot above).

Steps to reproduce:

- Navigate to Stack Overflow profile page (you may need an old account with a significant amount of rep).
- Select the whole history or a period of several years to display on the widget below the graph.

That's it.  When I do this I see the reputation graph display a few clumps of bars per the screenshot above.

Comment: Technically, the upper chart shows only 1 day, too much data maybe ?

Comment: It's showing 'Jan 1' but I'm not so sure it isn't truncating the year off the dates.  Either way, there's still something funky with the rendering.